# Fixed 'thead' width doesn't match with the 'tbody' width

Tags: html, css

I have a table that has the `<thead>` fixed, but each `<th>` in it doesn't match with the width of the respective columns (`<td>` in the `<tbody>`).

If you need more info just ask me. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** This is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8k0L551t/)

Comment: Don't let people fish for information. Read your question back like somebody who knows nothing about your code or your problem.

Comment: Could you please post your code on jsfiddle, because it's a bit hard visualising the problem without any code.

Comment: Yes, we need more info

Comment: add HTML and CSS to your question

Comment: Already post the Jsfiddle

Comment: Solution: comment out the `position:fixed` in the thead. I believe you may have been looking for `table-layout:fixed` instead.

Comment: @MrLister but I need the `<thead>` be present when user scroll down the page.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adding `table-layout:fixed` to the table and `display:table` to the thead fixes your problem.

Modified CSS:

```
table thead {
  display:table;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: fixed;
}
table{
  table-layout:fixed;
}
```

This is kind of a sloppy fix though, since the `table-layout:fixed` affects the entire layout and might not look how you want it to.

You could also set percentage widths on the columns instead of using `table-layout:fixed` for more control over the layout.